# Need to call removeObserver twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing, dealloc

I have a view that observe values of itself on `init` like this :

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"focusPointOfInterestIndicator" options:0 context:kSRCameraViewObserverContext];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"exposurePointOfInterestIndicator" options:0 context:kSRCameraViewObserverContext];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"paused" options:0 context:kSRCameraViewObserverContext];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"previewLayerGravity" options:0 context:kSRCameraViewObserverContext];
```

And on `dealloc`, observers are removed as they should be like this :

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"focusPointOfInterestIndicator"];
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"exposurePointOfInterestIndicator"];
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"paused"];
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"previewLayerGravity"];
```

But **unless calling it twice** (with or without context, doesn't change anything), I have a crash when the view is deallocated cause the value are still observed.
But I'm quite sure observers are added only once (since it's in init of object).

I just wonder if why it could be registered twice ? Or is it like by calling it twice, it let to the object to effectively remove observers ? If someone have any clue ?

Comment: Can you post a bit more of code ?

Comment: Here the exact code: https://github.com/sridenour/SRCameraView

Comment: Are you sure `sharedSetup` isn't being called more than once?  I would create an instance variable `_setup` and set that to `YES` to avoid double calls.  I am fairly certain this is the issue.

Comment: The idea is good, but still I don't see why it would be called twice :/ (will try it)

Comment: I confirm it's called twice yes

Comment: Because init is the primary initializer of NSObjet that means init must be called in Apple's implementation of initWithCoder / initWithFrame with something like [super init];

Comment: My bad, I should have thought about it, thanks pal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init` is the **primary initializer** of `NSObjet` that means init must be called in Apple's implementation of `initWithCoder` / `initWithFrame` with something like `[super init];`

so your `sharedSetup` is called twice

*EDIT (thanks to And Ainu):*

To be more specific, that's the `init` method of `UIView` which calls the `initWithFrame` method.

Comment: In fact it's the `init` method of `UIView` which call the `initWithFrame` method

Answer (score 1):

Its good practice if you use try catch every time you remove the observer.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    @try {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"LocationSelected" object:nil];
    } @catch (id anException){
        //do nothing, obviously it wasn't attached because an exception was thrown
   }   
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"LocationSelected" object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock: ^(NSNotification *not) {
       //Someone posted the notification handle it here
    }];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
     @try {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"LocationSelected" object:nil];
     } @catch (id anException){
         //do nothing, obviously it wasn't attached because an exception was thrown
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you can do is instead of observing in `init` method replace the same in `loadView` or `awakeFromNib` method. Then it will not called twice.